# remove last NA values in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table, na

I am running forecasts on data.tables that sometimes have NA values in the tail. These values are not yet available and can be removed. How do I remove NA values at the end of a series?

```
library(data.table)

DT = data.table(x=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9)
DT[c(4, 8:9), v := NA]

# required output:
DT[, head(.SD, 7 )]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the last non-`NA` and keep everything up to it:

```
DT[ seq( max(which(!is.na(v))) ) ]
```

Similarly, you could use `which.max` from the reverse:

```
DT[ seq( .N-which.max(rev(!is.na(v)))+1L ) ]
```

Both options work fine if there are no `NA` to drop at the end.

They behave differently if `v` is entirely `NA`:

- `max(which(!is.na(v)))` will give `-Inf` because `which` will return an empty vector.
  This makes `seq` throw an error.
- `which.max(rev(!is.na(v))` will return `1` because `FALSE` is the max value, found in position 1.
  This means all rows are returned.

If you want some other behavior in that case (like returning no rows), it should be simple to work out.